# In Google's IAB, can I get the product title and price before I call the launchpurchaseflow method?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a program that sets an alert dialog that asks "Would you like to purchase "TITLE" for "PRICE""

I know that the Google IAB library has a getSku() call but that's only available after a result from purchasing the item. Is there a way to get these two variables before any purchasing? Thanks.

*I might have seen an item that queries a bundle of sku's which lists out all the items, but I may be wrong*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution for this. first of all you will need the sku/product id.

```
public void getProductDetails(String sku) throws RemoteException, JSONException {
    logDebug("getProductDetails - " + sku);

    ArrayList<String>  skuList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add the specific sku
    skuList.add(sku);

    if (sku != null) {
         Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
         querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuList);
         Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, mContext.getPackageName(),  ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, querySkus);
         ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList(RESPONSE_GET_SKU_DETAILS_LIST);

         for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
             SkuDetails d = new SkuDetails(thisResponse);
             logDebug("Looking at sku details: " + d);
             purchaseTitle = d.getTitle(); // these are set as variables so you can call them
             purchasePrice = d.getPrice(); // whenever you want
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using in-app billing version 3 and need to fetch subscription product details, for which i have done in function "mGotInventoryListener"
if (inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_INFINITE_SUBSCRIPTION) != null) {
    Log.e(TAG,"product details price==== "+ inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_INFINITE_SUBSCRIPTION).getPrice());
    
   }
But i am getting data as null

Answer (score 2):

use this method in IABHelper:

```
 List<String> moreSkus = new ArrayList<String>();
  moreSkus.add("sku1");
  moreSkus.add("sku2");              

  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, moreSkus, mGotInventoryListener);
```

I test it works ok ,you can add inapp or sub type sku to list ,and return all details in invenroty

Comment: Will it works with IAB V2. I am getting the error like "queryInventoryAsync" not found. If not possible, please let me know is there any other way to get the product details with V2